# How do I indicate my role (e.g. AS SYSDBA) in Liquibase?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I'm now trying to connect to an Oracle database. And I can only connect by using a specific role (in this case, since I'm connecting as SYS, I will need the role SYSDBA to connect to the database).

If not, it will result in the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

How do I specify that in liquibase?

Answer (score 3):

If using a liquibase.properties file:

```
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
username=sys as sysdba
password=password1234
```

If using command line parameters:

```
./liquibase --username='sys as sysdba' --changeLogFile=etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better if you connect as a user who has the SYSDBA privilege. You can grant the sysdba privilege with the following command in sqlplus after connecting as sysdba

`grant sysdba to {user}`

Althought Im not quite sure why you would need to login as SYS in liquibase. Take a look at the following [article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2659418700346202574) and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-and-system-accounts-in-oracle-databases)

Comment: Turns out I don't need to. Thanks!